# How to add a HTML5 tag to AntiSamy policy file?

Tags: sanitization, antisamy

My AntiSamy file does not seem to like the HTML5 `<figure>` tag. Its allowing the tag itself to exist, but nothing contained inside it.

So this:

```
<figure> <img src="image/path"/> </figure>
```

Is becoming this:

```
<figure> </figure> <img src="image/path"/>
```

How can I stop the antisamy from stripping out the content of the `<figure>` tag? I want it to allow the `<figure>` tag and all its attributes and content.

Comment: I am having the same issue. You got anything on this ?

Comment: @VikasVats nope. I've tried everything and I can't get it to work.

Comment: This seems to be a real issue. HTML5 and CSS3 are both not covered in the config files for antiSamy. I am trying to add a simple border-radius to the xml file, and it keeps stripping out parts of the css that I am testing with.