# Why does OWASP AntiSamy strip out the figure tag?

Tags: html, sanitization, owasp, antisamy

My AntiSamy is stripping the `<figure>` tag.

So this:

```
<figure> <img src="image/path"/> </figure>
```

Is becoming this:

```
<figure> </figure> <img src="image/path"/>
```

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: I wonder if Antisamy has a version that can handle HTML5 tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a HTML5 tag to AntiSamy policy file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427087/how-to-add-a-html5-tag-to-antisamy-policy-file)